# How can I programatically change menu in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I've created one menu in Norwegian `menu_no` and one in English `menu_en`.

[image]

I can see that my theme supports only one menu, but I'm not planning on using more that one menu at a time. So when user selects English language, how can I change the active menu?

I've not found anything on Google and I can't find the right function in `nav-menu.php`.

**UPDATE**
I found quite a simple solution for my problem. I just had to think a bit differently. In my `functions.php`I added this code:

```
add_action('init', 'register_menus');

function register_menus(){
    register_nav_menus( array(
        'menu_no' => 'Norwegian menu',
        'menu_en' => 'English menu',
    ) );
}
```

and in my `header.php` file I use this code:

```
global $lang;

$args = array(
    'theme_location' => 'menu_'.$lang,
    'container'         => false
);


<?php wp_nav_menu($args); ?>
```

Voila. I'll post it as answer later - if not anyone else comes up with a better idea.

Comment: Are you using a plugin? The plugin may have a function you can use to check the selected language. You can then use that function in your template to display the relevant menu,

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/58164/assign-menus-to-theme-locations-with-theme-activation

Comment: You can use qtranslate plugin it will automatically change the language of menus on change of language..

Comment: I'm not planning on using any plugins. I just need to select a different menu.

Comment: Then you need to create a function to display/hide menus according to the active language Please share the code what you have tried so far..

Comment: I fixed it. It was actually quite easy. I'll post code later as the answer.

Comment: and where/when does the `$lang` gets set ? by the user ?

Comment: @Francisco, it can be a cookie or a user meta data for registered users.

Answer (score 0):

Paste this code into your `function.php` file

```
// Register Navigation Menus
function custom_navigation_menus() {
  $locations = array(
    'first_menu' => __( 'Menu for English language', 'text_domain' ),
    'second_menu' => __( 'Menu for Other Language', 'text_domain' ),
  );
  register_nav_menus( $locations );
}
   
// Hook into the 'init' action

add_action( 'init', 'custom_navigation_menus' );
```

You can customize the above code.
Now use `wp_nav_menu` function to display anywhere you want like this

```
<?php

wp_nav_menu( array(
  'menu' => 'primary',
  'theme_location' => 'first_menu',
);

?>
```

```
<?php

wp_nav_menu( array(
  'menu' => 'secondary',
  'theme_location' => 'second_menu',
);

?>
```

You can display each menu in different places. Now you to Option in you menu Primary and Secondary.

Comment: what does the `text_domain` is for ?.  How does *wp_nav_menu* knows which menu to use ?. Where did you create the menus ?

Comment: text_domain : you can replace that with your theme name that is optional. wp_nav_menu : you can learn on codex about it. it will know from theme_location name which you choose. And for you last question : I use generatewp.com for generating the code but I know the code completely